# Detect when app enters in freeform window mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

Is there any system wide event to know when an app has gone into a freeform window mode?

I tried to use Accessibility Service's AccessibilityWindowInfo.isInPictureInPictureMode(), this does not work because freeform is different than PIP mode.

Comment: the `freeform` tag wiki says the following : `The free form layout was introduced in Fortran 90. This source-code dialect for Fortran allows overcoming the limitations of the (previous) fixed format (either 77 or 132 columns). There are some differences between the two, for instance continuation lines. Fortran compilers typically rely on the source code suffix (i.e. file extension) to determine whether to use one or another dialect.`

Comment: i highly doubt that's the tag you're looking for, but the tag isn't very clear at all, so i guess it's fine to leave it like it is, but in future i don't think this tag will help you find an answer :)

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yeah thank you for pointing that out. Changed the tag.